# PHP in JavaScript file not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to echo my base url with my CI application in my main js file as so:

`var url = "<?php echo base_url('association/') ?>" + $(this).attr("id");`

and what I end up with is this:

`<?php echo base_url('association/') ?>120`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In javascript (.js) files you cannot execute php code.

Comment: unless configured otherwise, web servers do not run `*.js` files through the php interpretor

Comment: A better option is to output this data into the dom, either as data attribute, or in a script block, then retrieve it in your js

Comment: Deleted my answer, thanks @NicolasBouvrette is right and that's a decent solution with more detail than my own.

Comment: As a quick hack you *can* just rename the file something like `main.js.php` ... dirtier than a public toilet in Soho but it does work.